# How to make pygame only load the graphics being shown on the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6

I'm creating a game with my team in Python and Pygame.
It is a 2d battle royale game based in zombsroyale.io.

As the map is really big, the game starts to lag because it is loading the entire map, even the parts that aren't being shown on screen.

We would like pygame to only load the graphics that are currently being shown on screen, and when you move, stop loading the graphics that now aren't being shown and load the new graphics.

How could we achieve this in Python 3?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: we've also checked that the game is less laggy when we set the screen window size to a smaller one (e.g. 680x680). How can we make the game's performance be good with a big window size (e.g. 1280x720)?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that I know of. You could divide the image up into a rectangular grid and only load those sub-images that comprise what's visible from the current position. You'd probably want to cache a certain maximum number to avoid loading all of them into memory at once. It would be a lot simpler if you could load the entire image into memory and keep it there, so it doesn't need to be done again.

Comment: You can load the map once at the beginning and save it on a separate surface, and then blit on the screen only the portion of the map shown on the screen. To do this, you need to keep track of the rectangles while the camera moves.

Comment: How really big is the map?

Comment: @martineau the map is 90000x90000, it is really big, or at least for a pygame game.

Comment: @Valentino Thanks for answering. Yes, but that will continue making the game laggy.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not solely the map. blitting the whole screen each frame is time consuming in general. The [pygame intro](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html) says "SDL has some other design limitations, things like full screen scrolling graphics can quickly bring your game down to unplayable speeds."

Comment: Yeah, that _is_ certainly a big map. I think one way to deal with it would be to use `mmap` to map the (uncompressed) pixel data from it into virtual memory and then use string slicing to extract and assemble the pixels that form the rectangular area within it that you want to display. `pygame` has an `image.fromstring()` function that allows creating a new surface from the assembled data. One advantage of this approach is that it would use the OS's virtual memory page handling to manage the amount of data actually held in physical memory.

Comment: If you have a map that big, keep in mind that you also dont need to blit every object on the entire map every frame! It is in most cases enough if you check what objects are visible on the screen and which ones are near you (e.g. within +20% of your screensize in every direction to cover sprites which are only halfway into your screen) and dont obj.blit() the rest. You will need to keep updating the positions of all objects, but not blitting 95% of available objects does give a bit of a performance boost ;)